# need help implementing facebook credits

Tags: php, facebook

I've read a few of the other posts on getting started with implementing Facebook credits and I've downloaded the sample code from github: https://github.com/facebook/credits-api-sample.

The only changes I had made to the sample code are:

- In index.php, I set the app ID.
- In callback.php, I set the app secret.

I've uploaded all these files to my server:

- index.php
- callback.php
- facebook.php
- facebookapi_php5_restlib.php
- xd_receiver.html
- assets folder

On the Facebook app edit page:

- The canvas url points to index.php.
- The credits callback field points to the callback.php file on my
  server.
- Added myself as a credits tester.

I have not registered my company. Is that required for testing?
I do not have a secure canvas url. Is that required? The app is in sandbox mode.

When I run the test app, I see the index page. When I click on the "Pay with Facebook" button, this error pops up:

> There was a problem processing your payment. Sorry, but we're having trouble processing your payment. You have not been charged for this transaction. Please try again.

When I close the dialog, there is a message:

> Transaction failed!
>
> Error message returned from Facebook:
>
> The entity (class EntApplication) backed by id  cannot be seen by the
>      current viewer 0 (EntID: )

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

I found out what the problems were:

1. In order to get this to work, you need to have the company registration filled out.
2. After that is done (and this was not obvious), you need to actually select the company from the drop down list. This is all done in the credits section.
3. You must have a secure canvas url set in the basic settings section (i.e. https://example.com/app/index.html)
4. I'm not sure if you have to have the callback as a secure url in order for the test to work, but it does make sense that this would be required.
5. The test will not work in sandbox mode.

Hopefully this will help others that may run into similar problems.

Now I have to figure out how to get this to work using the facebook-actionscript sdk.

Comment: Actually, this is specifically NOT a forum. Read the [FAQ] for more info.

Comment: Uh, I read the FAQ. Don't know what you mean "this is NOT a forum". I had a programming problem and asked a question.

Comment: Since you remarked, _Wow. No responses what-so-ever since I posted this question yesterday. Hmm. Is this an active forum?_, I was merely pointing out that SO is not in fact a forum. Note that your answer has since been edited and that sentence has been removed.

Comment: None of the above is true: my testing app doesn't have a company (you only have to choose a country), I'm testing in HTTP, my payment handler is also hosted over HTTP (HTTPS is not needed), my secure canvas URL is not set, my app is in sandbox mode. Make sure that you're setting the HTTP response Header Content-Type to the value of the HTTP request Content-Type